# Incoming HTTP Requests with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

JMeter provides a simple HTTP server, the HTTP Mirror Server (https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server), which causes JMeter to simply mirror back any request that is sent to it.

Instead of mirroring a given request, is there a way for JMeter to accept a request and then, based on the request, execute a series of actions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use i.e. a [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) which allows execution of arbitrary [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) (or Java) code so you should be able to develop logic parsing incoming request and conditionally switch to this or that actions branch.

Test plan outline

- Thread Group

  - Beanshell Sampler
  - If Controller (condition 1)

    - action 1
    - action 2
  - If Controller (condition 2)

    - action 3
    - action 4

In Beanshell Sampler place custom code which will listen to incoming HTTP connections and set a JMeter variable basing on outcome via [vars.put](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method

In the If Controller you can put a condition checking variable value like

- In "If Controller (condition 1)" -  `"${myVariable}"=="foo"`
- In "If Controller (condition 2)" -  `"${myVariable}"=="bar"`

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for detailed information on Beanshell scripting and pre-defined variables and [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) documentation entry for information on setting correct conditions.